# Number of equal subsequences of two strings S1 and S2 with the last char of S1 matched

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two strings S1 & S2 of different length, what is the efficient approach to find the number of equal subsequences of both S1 and S2 with last char of S1 matched.

> e.g)
>
> S1 = ayb
>
> S2 = axbxxb

In this case there are two equal subsequences are present,

```
 "b"  => S1[2],S2[2]
 "b"  => S1[2],S2[5]
 "ab" => S1[0],S2[0] and S1[2],S2[2]
 "ab" => S1[0],S2[0] and S1[2],S2[5]
```

I know this can be solved using Dynamic programming, it would be great if someone gives idea to approach this problem efficiently.

Comment: I don't think this is called a "subsequence" EDIT: Ignore me, it is a subsequence

Comment: @Argote then what is a "subsequence"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a regular expression match problem.

First let's get rid of the "last character matches" condition. We want to reduce the problem to a "plain number of equal subsequences problem, without any conditions.

Suppose S1="a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub>Z". Let S1'="a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub>". Suppose further there are N occurrences of Z in S2. For each occurrence we can write

Suppose there are N occurrences of Z in S2. For each occurrence *i* we can write S2<sub>i</sub>="b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>k<sub>i</sub></sub>Zb<sub>k<sub>i</sub>+1</sub>...". Assume S2'="b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>k<sub>i</sub></sub>". Now solve the plain problem for S1' and S2'<sub>i</sub>, for each i in 1..N.

Now, how to solve the plain problem?

Take the shorter string, say it's S1. Let's now write it `"abc…t"`. Transform it into `".*a?.*b?.*…t?.*"`. This is your regular expression. You now need to count how many ways there are for the regular expression to match S2. The match can be done with an NFA-based algorithm.

To actually count the number of matches, one needs to understand the internal workings of an NFA-based match algorithm. There's a set of states that are active at any given moment. A state can split in two, or two states can merge. A state can die if it encounters a wrong character. So you assign a score of 1 to the initial state. When a state splits, each new state inherits the parent's score. When two states merge, the new state gets the sum of the scores. When a state dies, its score is dropped.

I'm not sure if this is any different from what you call the dynamic programming approach. There are up to 2<sup>N</sup> matches, so on some inputs this *will* take a long time.

**Update**: It looks like it should be also possible to solve the "last character matches" problem directly, without reducing it to the plain problem. Suppose there are 2 occurrences of Z in S2: S2="ab…pZq…yZ". (One can ignore all characters after the last Z anyway). One can build a regex out of S2: `".*a?.*b?.*…p?.*(Z|Z?.*q?.*…y?.*Z)"`. More occurrences are handled in the same way. A seemingly redundant regexp is needed to maintain the correct number of matches (not just the fact that there's a match).

Comment: are you sure this is a regex problem? no way to solve with DP?